# Convenient way to start a custom OCaml toplevel in Emacs with tuareg

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

If I start a custom toplevel in Emacs/tuareg with the `tuareg-run-caml` function, I need to give the path to the toplevel and the various `-I` options it requires to find the CMI files.  This typing is tedious, is there a more convenient way to start a custom toplevel?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to add a `.ocamlinit` in the project directory that uses `#directory` to add whatever paths are necessary to the toplevel. You can also use this to install printers, add shorter names for commonly used modules, run test code, etc.

Note that you probably want that project specific `.ocamlinit` to execute `~/.ocamlinit`, since things like opam tend to put bits and pieces in there. It might look something like this:

```
#use "/home/foo/.ocamlinit"

#directory "_build"

open Printf
module V = VeryLongModuleName
```

Note that `#use` expects a hard-coded path. This unfortunately interferes with distributing the file.

I further automate this by having an emacs command to start a toplevel that searches the current directory for a file called `*.top` to execute, falling back to `ocaml` if none is found. As `ocamlbuild` provides a fairly simple method of building these files, this avoids much of the tedium of getting a project loaded into a useable toplevel.